# Loading and position image, when the another images are loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small problem with loading and position one of my images. The smallest one. I'm using spacegallery script (http://www.eyecon.ro/spacegallery/).

It's loading good, but i want it to position it in the corner of bigger image, and when i load my page for the first time, it's not positioned, when i reload it - it's all fine, but the first loading is wrong.

Here are the screens:
It's the first load without refreshing the site:

[first load http://derivativeofln.com/withoutload.png](http://derivativeofln.com/withoutload.png)

Second and next loads:

[second load http://derivativeofln.com/withload.png](http://derivativeofln.com/withload.png)

My HTML:

```
    <div id="myGallery" class="spacegallery">   

    <img class="imaz" src=http://derivativeofln.com/magnifier.jpg />
    <img class="aaa" src=images/bw1.jpg alt="" atr1="bw1" />
    <img class="aaa" src=images/bw2.jpg alt="" atr1="bw2" />
    <img class="aaa" src=images/bw3.jpg alt="" atr1="bw3" />

            </div>
```

MY CSS:

```
#myGallery0 {
width: 100%;
height: 300px;
 }

#myGallery0 img {
border: 2px solid #52697E;
 }

a.loading {
background: #fff url(../images/ajax_small.gif) no-repeat center;
}

.imaz {
 z-index: 10000; 
}


.imaz img{
position: absolute;
left:10px;
top:10px;
z-index: 10000;
width: 35px;
height: 35px;   
}
```

My Jquery main script file: (the first positioning instructions are on the bottom, so feel free to scroll down : ))

```
(function($){
   EYE.extend({

    spacegallery: {



        animated: false,

        //position images 
        positionImages: function(el) {

            var top = 0;

            EYE.spacegallery.animated = false;
            $(el)
                .find('a')
                    .removeClass(el.spacegalleryCfg.loadingClass)
                    .end()
                    .find('img.aaa')
                    .removeAttr('height')
                    .each(function(nr){
                        var newWidth = this.spacegallery.origWidth - (this.spacegallery.origWidth - this.spacegallery.origWidth * el.spacegalleryCfg.minScale) * el.spacegalleryCfg.asins[nr];

                        $(this)
                            .css({
                                top: el.spacegalleryCfg.tops[nr] + 'px',
                                marginLeft: - parseInt((newWidth + el.spacegalleryCfg.border)/2, 10) + 'px',
                                opacity: 1 - el.spacegalleryCfg.asins[nr]
                            }) 
                            .attr('width', parseInt(newWidth));
                        this.spacegallery.next = el.spacegalleryCfg.asins[nr+1];
                        this.spacegallery.nextTop = el.spacegalleryCfg.tops[nr+1] - el.spacegalleryCfg.tops[nr];
                        this.spacegallery.origTop = el.spacegalleryCfg.tops[nr];
                        this.spacegallery.opacity = 1 - el.spacegalleryCfg.asins[nr];
                        this.spacegallery.increment = el.spacegalleryCfg.asins[nr] - this.spacegallery.next;
                        this.spacegallery.current = el.spacegalleryCfg.asins[nr];
                        this.spacegallery.width = newWidth;
                    })

        },


        //constructor
        init: function(opt) {
            opt = $.extend({}, EYE.spacegallery.defaults, opt||{});
            return this.each(function(){
                var el = this;
                if ($(el).is('.spacegallery')) {
                    $('<a href="#"></a>')
                        .appendTo(this)
                        .addClass(opt.loadingClass)
                        .bind('click', EYE.spacegallery.next);

                    el.spacegalleryCfg = opt;
                    var listunia, images2 = [], index;
                    listunia = el.getElementsByTagName("img");

                    for (index = 1; index < listunia.length; ++index) {
                        images2.push(listunia[index]);
                    } 


                    el.spacegalleryCfg.images = images2.length;             
                    el.spacegalleryCfg.loaded = 0;
                    el.spacegalleryCfg.asin = Math.asin(1);
                    el.spacegalleryCfg.asins = {};
                    el.spacegalleryCfg.tops = {};
                    el.spacegalleryCfg.increment = parseInt(el.spacegalleryCfg.perspective/el.spacegalleryCfg.images, 10);
                    var top = 0;

                    $('img.aaa', el)
                        .each(function(nr){
                            var imgEl = new Image();
                            var elImg = this;

                            el.spacegalleryCfg.asins[nr] = 1 - Math.asin((nr+1)/el.spacegalleryCfg.images)/el.spacegalleryCfg.asin;
                            top += el.spacegalleryCfg.increment - el.spacegalleryCfg.increment * el.spacegalleryCfg.asins[nr];
                            el.spacegalleryCfg.tops[nr] = top;
                            elImg.spacegallery = {};
                            imgEl.src = this.src;
                            if (imgEl.complete) {

                                el.spacegalleryCfg.loaded ++;
                                elImg.spacegallery.origWidth = imgEl.width;
                                elImg.spacegallery.origHeight = imgEl.height
                            } else {
                                imgEl.onload = function() {
                                    el.spacegalleryCfg.loaded ++;
                                    elImg.spacegallery.origWidth = imgEl.width;
                                    elImg.spacegallery.origHeight = imgEl.height
                                    if (el.spacegalleryCfg.loaded == el.spacegalleryCfg.images) {

                                        EYE.spacegallery.positionImages(el);

                                    }
                                };
                            }
                        });




                    el.spacegalleryCfg.asins[el.spacegalleryCfg.images] = el.spacegalleryCfg.asins[el.spacegalleryCfg.images - 1] * 1.3;
                    el.spacegalleryCfg.tops[el.spacegalleryCfg.images] = el.spacegalleryCfg.tops[el.spacegalleryCfg.images - 1] * 1.3;
                    if (el.spacegalleryCfg.loaded == el.spacegalleryCfg.images) {


                            if(el.spacegalleryCfg.images == 3){
                            $('img.imaz', this).css('top', '27px'); // HERE IS POSITIONING OF MY IMAGES, WHEN SCRIPT LOADS FOR THE FIRST TIME!
                            $('img.imaz', this).css('left', (($(el).find('img.aaa:last').width())/2 + 77) + 'px' );
                            }
                            else if(el.spacegalleryCfg.images==2){
                                $('img.imaz', this).css('top', '33px');     
                                $('img.imaz', this).css('left', (($(el).find('img.aaa:last').width())/2 + 77) + 'px' ); // HERE IT ENDS:)
                            }

                        EYE.spacegallery.positionImages(el);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Could I point you towards [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org/)? Kudos for including code, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems to be a cache thing
try to specify image dimensions (width and height) on your html, because on first load (images not in cache) the browser only knows dimensions after the load and the positioning might not be correct.

in alternative you can run your positioning code when the document is loaded

```
$(document).ready(«your poisitioning function here»)
```

see http://api.jquery.com/ready/ for that jquery ready function

Comment: Ok, but where you suggest to put $(document).ready instruction? You know, i have a few this type galleries on one page : )

Comment: jquery allows severall .ready functions and they all will run (its a list) so i sugest they stay near the positioning code where it is relevant (or somewhere else you thing they are relevant).